# WCF HTTP GET api

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

In my .NET project, I have to use HTTP GET request to get weather info for my city from API. Because of my JavaScript background I thought "OK, so all I need is something like `app.get(url, body)`", so I started with something like this:

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var responseString = client.DownloadString("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=" + city + "&CountryName=" + country);
            string xmlString = DecodeXml(responseString);

            return xmlString;
        }
```

Unfortunately for me it turned out, that I have to use WCF to get the data. I searched the web for some tutorials, but I couldn't find anything with getting the data from outer sources, just creating own API.

I'm not a native speaker, so maybe I'm just out of words to look for the solution, but it would be awesome if you could give me some advice.

Comment: How to call particular API depends on Weather API you are using..

Comment: And it is not clear from your description about your overall need here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio. Add Service Reference, and then type "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx" into the address and hit Go. It'll auto-generate the end point for you to use.

Then the code is something like:

```
        ServiceReference1.GlobalWeatherSoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.GlobalWeatherSoapClient("GlobalWeatherSoap");
        string cities = client.GetCitiesByCountry("Hong Kong");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just use HTTP GET, you can do something like this:

```
var city = "Dublin";
var country = "Ireland";

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
    "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=" + 
    city + 
    "&CountryName=" + country);

request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

reader.Close();
response.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Please note, I have not HTML decoded the response here, you can simply use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode for that.

Also, you will need to include the following using statements:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
```